# How to workaround warning C4333 ('>>' : right shift by too large amount, data loss)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I have the following function to convert an integer of arbitrary size to a buffer:

```
template<typename T>
std::string build_data_from(T val)
{
  std::string result;

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(val); i++)
  {
    result.insert(0, 1, char(val));
    val = val >> 8;
  }

  return result;
};
```

However, invoking the template function with an *unsigned char* renders a warning in Visual C++ 2008:

```
std::string x(build_data_from<unsigned char>(1));
```

> warning C4333: '>>' : right shift by
>   too large amount, data loss

Is there any clean way (without using a *pragma warning* directive) to workaround it?

Comment: you could specialize the template function for the unsigned char case. This is however just a workaround that requires double coding

Comment: You could also extract and specialize only the bitshift function.

Comment: @king_nak: not really double coding, there is no loop / bit-shifting required for `char` and `unsigned char` so the methods are much easier.

Comment: @UncleBens: but what's the point of looping and shifting for a 8-bits type ;) ?

Comment: The #pragma is obvious.  If that's verboten then I'd just test on  sizeof(val) == 1.  The code generator gets rid of it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple: overloading `build_data_from` for `unsigned char` (and `char`).

This can be done either by a plain overload or using `std::enable_if`, I'd advise a plain overload as it'll be easier:

```
std::string build_data_from(char val)
{
  std::string result; result += val; return result;
}

std::string build_data_from(unsigned char val)
{
  return build_data_from(char(val));
}
```

But, you are conscious that casting an `unsigned char` to a `char` might produce some weird output right ? (I mean that `unsigned char` might have values that are not really printable)

Answer (score 4):

The following will get rid of he warning.

change

```
val = val >> 8;
```

to

```
val = val >> 7 >> 1;
```

or

```
val = (val >> 7 >> 1) & 0xff;
```

Comment: Don't know why the other solutions had more upvotes... this seems like the cleanest/simplest solution... works for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this with a single `if`-statement:

```
template<typename T>
std::string build_data_from(T val)
{
  std::string result;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(val); i++)
  {
    result.insert(0, 1, char(val));
    if (sizeof (T) > 1)
      val = val >> 8;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Since the conditional `if (sizeof(T) > 1)` is constant for any `T` the compiler will optimize it away, so no runtime overhead and no warnings. For the case that `T` is a `char` you even get slightly faster code because the shift gets optimized away.

Btw: You should declare your `i` variable as `size_t`, not `int`. the result of `sizeof()` is `size_t` and some compilers (gcc for example) warn you if you do a comparison between signed and unsigned integers.

Comment: I think you meant `sizeof(T) > 1` since `sizeof` gives the number of `char`, not the number of bits. Also, the loop is spurious for `char` and `unsigned char`, and there is no need to call `insert` at all since the data can be appended... much easier to overload :)

Comment: Your proposal still renders a warning. I've accepted Matthieu's solution.

Comment: I've changed the `i` variable declaration, though. Thanks.